# IntelliTrace: Uncaught exception during type initialization

Tags: visual-studio, intellitrace

Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3.
.Net 3.5 SP1, AnyCPU

Today I often get this error for my project:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Process:
>   D:\projects\vs-2015\sharp_sandbox\sharp_sandbox\bin\Debug\sharp_sandbox.vshost.exe
>   Automatically attaching to support this behavior was not completely
>   successful.
>
> Successfully attached these type(s) of code: Managed
>
> Failed to attach to these type(s) of code:
>   IntelliTrace: Uncaught
>   exception during type initialization.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you do when this error occurs? Are you trying to run IntelliTrace from command line? Are you debugging?

Comment: Where do you actually see this error? In Visual Studio, in Event Log?

Comment: I debug my application. I get it each time when I open my Project in IDE and when debugging is finished. I don't try to run IntelliTrace from command line. This error mesage I see in the dialog window.

Comment: A few more questions. 1. What kind of project do you have? Web, console....? 2. Do you want to use IntelliTrace at all? 3. Do you use the managed/native code interoperability?

Comment: This is a simple console project. You can download and watch it here https://yadi.sk/d/kr9_SATXu8xgx . I don't try to use IntelliTrace. I get this problem only for this project.

Comment: My code uses some WinAPI functions. But *the same* code source file in my other project haven't the problem with IntelliTrace.

Comment: You may try to play with "Enable Debuggers" settings. You will find it in Debug tab in the project properties. For example try to check/uncheck "Enable native code debugging".

Comment: Thank you! If I switch on the *Enable native code debugging* option, then this problem disappears. If I switch off this option then problem appeares again. Post your message as an answer for I could mark it like an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check/uncheck *Enable native code debugging* configuration option. You will find it in *Enable Debuggers* section it in *Debug* tab in the project properties.